# How to get line breaks between every merged file content and all paths of all txt in one txt (batch, subfolders)?

Tags: batch-file, merge, concatenation, line-breaks, subdirectory

```
chcp 1252
for /r "C:\1" %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> echo 2> "C:\2\x.txt"
```

I want to overwrite x.txt if I use this batch again. 2>&1 is important to get the paths and line breaks in x.txt. I want the paths and content of all txt files (this folder, all subfolders) in an alphabetical order. It creates all content in a single file. But it don't overwrite the existing content and there are no line breaks with path (2>&1). How can I integrate it?

Comment: You will need to get a list of the files and folders before you use the `TYPE` command.  You can do that with a `FOR /R` command.

Comment: I don't know how to combine my code with for /r. chcp 1252 for /r type "C:\1*.txt" > "C:\1\x.txt" 2>&1 is not working.

Comment: read `for /?` for the correct syntax.

Comment: I can see that you didn't even make an attempt at reading the help file or even Google searching for the correct syntax based on the example in your comment.

Comment: Do not put code in comments.  Update your question with your new code.

Comment: A simple echo 2> "C:\2\x.txt" before the for cycle would do

Comment: It won't work for me. Please have a look in my code on top. It generates echo and 2.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(for /r "C:\1" %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f")>"C:\2\x.txt" 2>&1
```

Put the whole `for` loop into a code block and redirect the whole thing just once. `2>&1` means "Write STDERR (Stream 2) to the same destination as STDOUT (Stream 1)"